# Trouble with cross network permissions for an image through iis7 in an asp.net virtual directory

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, permissions

- I have load balanced web servers
- My application has a function that allows the user to upload their company logo to display in the application header
- obviously, when they upload the logo image file, it needs to be in a central location or otherwise, the file will not be accessible to the other server on the load balancer.
- in order to be able to upload the image through the application other one of either servers and then display it on both servers I need a virtual directory on both servers that point to a third "file server" (this is the "AcctData" directory shown below with a sub folder "images")

the problem is  that no matter what I do, I run into a permissioning issue
 -

[image]

If I use pass-through authentication I get a 401 error.  If I use a specific user that's set up on both boxes, I get a 500 error.  I've also tried sticking a Web.config file in the "AcctData" directory allowing anonymous access.  Nothing is working though.

[image]

Comment: if you use Active Directory, will it work if you use an AD user's credentials that has permissions to the 3rd server?

Comment: @derek - the Application Pool uses an AD user as its identity so the pass-through should use those same credentials, correct?  Also, that same Domain User used in the App Pool identity has read/write perms on the AcctData directory and sub directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  If I edit "Anonymous Authentication" and select Application Pool Identity it works like it should.